# Switch outputs in R shiny radio buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app where I am using `radioGroupButtons` from ShinyWidgets. So for each button I am trying to switch to different output like table or a plot. How do I link the radio button to the outputs

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinipsum)
library(htmlwidgets)

  ui <- navbarPage(
    div(
      id = "section1-1",
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "Id069",
        # label = "Choose a graph :",
        choices = c(
          `<i class='fa fa-bar-chart'></i>` = "bar",
          `<i class='fa fa-line-chart'></i>` = "line",
          `<i class='fa fa-pie-chart'></i>` = "pie"
        ),
        justified = TRUE
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # observe({
    #   x <- input$inRadioButtons
    #   
    #   # Can also set the label and select items
    #   updateRadioButtons(session, "inRadioButtons2",
    #                      label = paste("radioButtons label", x),
    #                      choices = x,
    #                      selected = x
    #   )
    # })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      random_ggplot()
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you can access the input ID like this:

```
         Value = input$Id069
```

So, add logic like this to server side (within output$plot):

```
        If (Value == x) {
          Plot1()
        } else {
          Plot2()
        }
```

You might want to look into conditional panels on the UI.